# Is there an API that allows you access to another person's gmail account?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I need read-only access to certain emails, kind of like how Route (the package tracking app) works. Does the Gmail API (or some other API) allow you access to accounts if the person ticks off a box that says they authorize you to access their email?

Comment: It would not be as simple as ticking a box, but there is an API. You'd have to get credentialed to access the account, then when you have that credential you can use, e.g., this API: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs

Comment: There's info about how to authorize your App with Gmail here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth#:~:text=During%20development%2C%20register%20the%20application,the%20credentials%20(if%20necessary).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, however you need to have the users' consent, either by using a refresh token, or if you have Google Workspace, you can have email delegation or impersonate a user via service account.

There's a good article about it
https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/impersonating-service-accounts

And here's the API you might want to use to get the messages of a user
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list

Comment: I think your first link is to an article about users impersonating service accounts, not the other way around.